# Node.js vs GCM for Android

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am going to make a project which uses 2 kinds of android apps.
1. Client App
2. Admin App

I need to push notifications/data in real time to both apps whenever there is a new data. There is no web interfaces, server is only for communication between these 2 app.

So my question is do I need to use node.js for this or should I handle it only with GCM ?

Comment: Use Firebase, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/